# Pro Tools and playback

Tags: pro-tools, sound, background, playback

When using Pro Tools, sound playback is only possible in the software, nothing else can use the sound card. But before I reinstalled Pro Tools I was able to use sound card for any playback with Pro Tools working, unfortunately I don't remember what was the exact settings used in that time. Maybe you know how to deal with this?

The main thing this bothers me is not being able to follow video tutorials while using software, like essential training for pro tools etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Windows or Mac?

Comment: Sorry, Windows 8.1. The same thing happens on Win 7.

Comment: Did you re-install the exact same version of Pro Tools? Which version?